# Normal Force of two objects

Tags: processing, game-physics

I'm making a simulation "game" with many circles in ProcessingJS attracted together by their own gravity. When several objects are sitting together and are in constant contact they will start to penetrate each other because they are being moved towards their collective center of mass.

How can I calculate and apply a normal force to stop this from happening? I have already tried finding if two objects are in contact and applying a force parallel to direction between them that is scaled based on their NetForce. This resulted in them sitting stably for a while then starting to rotate and move around seemingly randomly. I have also tried scaling the force based on their relative velocity but that didn't work at all;

tl;dr How can I calculate the normal force between two(or more) free moving spheres given their mass, initial Force vector, and relative position

Comment: No easy solution. One approch is iterative. Create a list of contacts, eg 3 objs a,b,c in contact will be `ab`, `bc`, `ca` , each pair in turn, move them (don't apply a force) along the line between them so they just touch. Do for each pair. Then repeat. The  more times you repeat the better the solution. You must make sure solutions are possible. The number touching one object can not be greater than can fit. Note there is still no guarantee of a solution. You can fix in place (relative to an abstract center of mass object ) those closest to center of mass to reduce the solution oscillating

Comment: ...And this can still result in overlap.

Comment: This seems more like a math question than a programming question. I'd go and do some research on the algorithm you want to implement before worrying about exactly how to implement it with code.